# Showing equality of 2 suprema in complete lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(M,+,0)$ be a naturally ordered commutative monoid (i.e. such that the natural preorder is antisymmetric) such that $(M,\sqsubseteq)$ is a complete lattice. Then $(M,\sum^*)$ is a summation structure with
$$\sum^* \alpha=\sup_{(
{\mathbb{M}},\sqsubseteq)}\left(\sum(\alpha|J) | J\in 2^{I}_{\text{fin}}\right),$$

> That is $M$ is a set and $\sum^*$ is a map that assigns to
>   $\alpha:I\to M$, $\sum^*\alpha$ with
>
> 1. If $\alpha:\{i\} \to M$, $\sum^* \alpha= \alpha i$.
> 2. Partitioning $I$ doesn't change the sum: For $\eta: I  \to A$ and $\beta : A\to M$ with $a\mapsto \sum^*(\alpha | \eta^{-1}a)$ always: $\sum^* \alpha = \sum^* \beta$.

Now

1. Let $\alpha:{i}\to M$, then $\sum^*\alpha=\sup\{\alpha i\}=\alpha i$.
2. For $\alpha:I\to M$, $\eta: I\to A$ and $\beta:A\to M$, with $\beta a=\sum^*(\alpha|\eta^{-1}a)$.

We have to show $\sum^*\alpha=\sum^* \beta$.

The inequality $\sum^* \beta \leq \sum^*\alpha $:
We have
$$\sum^*\beta=\sup_{A_0\subseteq A}\sum_{a\in A_0}\beta a=\sup_{A_0}\sum_{a} \sum^* (\alpha|\eta^{-1}a)=\sup_{A_0}\sum_a\sup_{J\subset \eta^{-1}a}\sum_{i\in J} \alpha i$$
Now the last supremum is less than the supremum taken over all finite subsets of $I$, that is 
$$ \leq \sup_{A_0}\sum_{a\in A_0}\sup_{J\subseteq I}\sum_{i\in J}\alpha i=\sum^*\alpha$$

For the other inequality: we want to show that $\sum^*\alpha=\sup_{J\in \mathfrak{I}}\sum_{i\in J}\alpha i \leq \sum^* \beta$. That is for every $J\in \mathfrak{I}$ it is to show
$$\sum_{i\in J}\alpha i\leq\sup_{A_0\in \mathfrak{A}}\sum_{a\in A_0} \sup_{J_a\subseteq_{\text{fin}}\eta^{-1}a}\sum_{i\in J_a}\alpha i.$$
For each $J$ it suffies to find one $A_0$ with 
$$\sum_{i\in J}\alpha i\leq \sum_{a\in A_0} \sup_{J_a \subseteq_{\text{fin}}\eta^{-1}a} \sum_{i\in J_a}\alpha i.$$
Pick $A_0=\eta J$ and for each $a \in \eta J$ the set $J_a=J\cap \eta^{-1}a$. Then we have $J=\cup_{a\in A_0}J_a=\cup_{a\in A_0} J \cap \eta^{-1}a$ and
$$\sum_{i\in J}\alpha i=\sum_{a\in \eta J}\sum_{i\in J_a} \alpha i.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "naturally ordered"? That the natural preorder is actually an order?

Comment: yes, meaning it is antisymmetric so $x+s+t=x\Rightarrow x+s=x$

Comment: The definition of the  summation structure is incomprehensible.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I have tried to make it more clear.

Comment: @orange.  It is the right hand side that is confusing,

Comment: @WilliamElliot in the definition of $\sum^*$ or $\beta a$?

Comment: @orange  What does (a|J)|J mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot the map $\alpha$ restricted on the set $J$ for $J$ finite subset of $I$

Comment: @WilliamElliot this is standard notation in monoid theory. see for exmp https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82783371.pdf